# Creating stored functions and triggers without SUPER privilege

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

All I am trying to do is create some stored functions and triggers that act on some tables. I find that, for either of those, I get MySQL error #1419 (`You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)`).

[image: Attempt with trigger]I checked the `user` table of `mysql`, and find that my username is `HeadAdmin` and my hostname is `%`. I tried setting DEFINER as `HeadAdmin@%`, but it doesn't work. I go back to `user` table, try setting it that way (a `Super_priv` column exists), and it still doesn't work (it literally is an error to do so).

I don't know how to use that `log_bin_trust_function_creators` variable, let alone **why** it's less safe. How can I create triggers and stored functions ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After pondering over Michael-sqlbot 's answer, I decided upon changing that `log_bin_trust_function_creators` variable to `1`. Until now, after looking on Google, and then AWS manual, I didn't know how.

According to [one of their manuals](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-mysql-functions/), there exists things called parameter groups (damn, AWS has a lot of stuff) which can be created, and RDS instances use. A parameter group is created by default, and from my attempt, the parameters in it are not editable (including the parameter I needed to edit). Long story short, I clicked on Parameter Groups from the RDS Dashboard menu. Then, I clicked the Create Parameter Group button, and then went through to creating it. Once that was finished, I went to Details page[image: The icon to click]
type in the parameter, click Edit Parameters, and select 1 for the value.

Finally, when all was said and done, I go back to Instances (from the RDS dashboard), right click the instance, hit Modify, and change the instance's selected Parameter Group to the one I just created. I wait for that to take effect, reboot the instance, and wait for the all clear.

Comment: This helped me a lot. I would have never able to figure out otherwise.

Answer (score 10):

Setting `log_bin_trust_function_creators=1` is "less safe" simply because it trusts that the users creating stored programs know what they are doing, rather than requiring that they hold the `SUPER` privilege (which should also imply that they know what they are doing).

The issue here is that in a replication environment, the some privilege controls are more relaxed in the replica server, potentially giving the user defining a stored program access to mechanisms for privilege escalation that wouldn't be available on the master server.   You may not have a replication environment,  now, but every MySQL Server is a potential replication master, so the explanation is still valid.

It's a dynamic variable, so it can be enabled at runtime, but that requires the logged-in user to have the `SUPER` privilege.  Add `log_bin_trust_function_creators=1` to the [mysqld] section of your defaults file and restart the server daemon to enable this.

---

Useful, somewhat related, tidbits:

If `SELECT @@BINLOG_FORMAT;` returns `STATEMENT`, change that to `MIXED` in the config file, `binlog_format=MIXED`.  `STATEMENT` is an old default value that should have been deprecated long ago, and can cause more grief for you when using stored programs.  `MIXED` avoids those issues, because `MIXED` can properly log statements that are not deterministic.  The other alternative, `ROW`, is even better in my experience, but `MIXED` is what the default value should have been.

When defining a stored *function*, be sure to declare it as `DETERMINISIC` if it is indeed deterministic and add `READS SQL DATA` if it uses tables but doesn't modify them, or add `NO SQL` if the function only does internal calculations but doesn't use tables.  A deterministic function will always return the same output if given the same input, for all invocations and across all rows within the execution of a single query.  There are cases where, if the server knows about this determinism, you'll get a performance benefit.

If you are inclined to write a function that is not deterministic, consider using a procedure instead.

Comment: Can you give me detailed instructions on how to set `log_bin_trust_function_creators` on Amazon Linux EC2 server? I don't know where to find defaults file, or [mysqld], or how to restart, on that server...

Comment: Very clear explanation.
If anyone need a detailed reasoning behind this error : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-logging.html